# WCF transactions

Tags: wcf, transactions

I imagine the following WCF service usage: (of a cash acceptor)

```
Service Consumer 1                           Service Consumer 2
cashAcceptorService.BeginTransaction();     cashAcceptorService.StopDevice();
                                            //this should throw exception: device is locked / used in a transaction                                     
cashAcceptorService.AcceptMoney();          

cashAcceptorService.EndTransaction();
```

Service Consumer 1 and 2 use the same WCF single instance. I wonder if this functionality is already implemented. Do WCF transactions offer this?

How do you see this done?

Answer (score 0):

If the following is true:

- The service is interacting with a transactional object (eg the database)
- The service has transaction flow enabled

Then WCF does indeed offer this.

The client can then use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class. Any transactions initiated on the client will flow through to the service automatically.

```
using(TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
     // Do stuff with the service here
     cashAcceptorService.AcceptMoney();
     //
     //
     transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Handling transactions in WCF tends to be an entire chapter of a book, but this should be enough information to get you on the right track.

Comment: Not using a database. I guess i can set the wcf service to have the flow enabled. But what if another service consumer calls stop while the device is in a transaction. I don't want others to disturb the device while in use. (calling some specific methods should directly fail)  Thanks!

Comment: WCF offers support for interacting with transactional components. It does not provide support for creating transactional components. I think you just have to write a locking mechanism that's separate from transactions.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to understand the concept of distributed transactions . I recommend to read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35087/Truly-Understanding-NET-Transactions-and-WCF-Imple